# array management for json schema in confluent schema registry

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jsonschema

currently I have a Kafka topic on which I'm writing the following json messages:

```json
{
  "messageType": "NEW",
  "timestamp": 1656582818024,
  "fieldId": 266,
  "number": 9835,
  "contains": [
    "56644630997",
    "06014134231",
    "06014134231"
  ]
}
```

Pleas note that I can write an arbitrary number of strings in "contains" list (one time I could have it empty or populated with nulls, other times I could have thousands of strings)

The message is then written in Parquet format on a S3 storage using Confluent's [S3 connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/overview.html).
This connector works fine reading the json schemas from the confluent schema registry.

My problem here is I don't understand how should I build the json schema for this particular message since I don't know how to manage arrays.

Here is my current tentative which it isn't working.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title":  "my_messages",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "messageType": {
      "type": ["string", "null"]
    },
    "timestamp": {
      "type": ["integer", "null"]
    },
    "fieldId": {
      "type": ["integer", "null"]
    },
    "number": {
      "type": ["integer", "null"]
    },
    "contains": {
      "type": ["array", "null"],
      "items": [
        {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

I'm fairly sure my kafka connector is breaking because the "contains" array is not validated in my schema.json.

Following I post the error I'm getting:
`caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Array schema did not specify the items type`

Lastly, if you have a complete link to schema json documentation it would be great.
Thank you for any help

Comment: Breaking how? Do you have a specific error? Regarding "_message is then written in Parquet format_". it is worth mentioning that the Parquet format requires an Avro conversion step (maybe this is your real error). So, would you be willing to change your producer code to use Avro? The "complete link" is just https://json-schema.org

Comment: For every other topics i'm able to write parquet messages, so the conversion is not a problem. It's the schema.json.
The error is: caused by: `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Array schema did not specify the items type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all elements of the array in "contains" to be validated, remove the extra nesting of that subschema in an array. That is, turn this:

```
    "contains": {
      "type": ["array", "null"],
      "items": [
        {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
      ]
    }
```

into this:

```
    "contains": {
      "type": ["array", "null"],
      "items": {
        "type": ["string", "null"]
      }
    }
```

Documentation is available here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html